# First method of Linq giving error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, linq, entity-framework

In my webmethod of my WCF rest service i am trying to find record using Linq's First method like below

```
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UpdateProductObject", Method = "PUT")]
    public Result UpdateProductObject(ProductObjectToSave prodSave)
    {

        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork((IObjectContext)_objectSetFactory);
        var versions = prodSave.VersionDetails;

        foreach (var versionDetail in versions)
        {
            var detail = versionDetail;

            var dbVersionentity = _productVersionEntityRepository.First(x => x.Id == detail.Id);

            if (detail.Id  < 0)
            {

                dbVersionentity.Id = GetNextTableId("vProductVersion");

            }

            dbVersionentity.Name = detail.Name;
            dbVersionentity.Code = detail.Name;

            if (detail.Id > 0){

            _productVersionEntityRepository.Update(dbVersionentity);
            }
            else
            {
                _productVersionEntityRepository.Insert(dbVersionentity);
            }


        }


        try
        {
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return new Result() { Error = e.Message };
        }

        return new Result() { Error = "Record updated successfully" };

    }
```

The "_productVersionEntityRepository" is defined as below in my service.

```
 private readonly Repository<ProductVersionEntity> _productVersionEntityRepository;
```

When there are no records it throws exception "Sequence contains no elements" . I have done some finding that we can use FirstOrDefault method. But somehow i am not getting that option to use FirstOrDefault. I am really new to this so may be i have missed some links where solution could have been described. Please help me or suggest me other way to do some error handling if First method fails

Comment: Could you post the code of `Repository<T>`?

Comment: Edited my answer, please take a look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way that [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) works, it will throw an exception if the element can't be found. You can use [FirstorDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) instead and check if the element is `null`.

Edit: I realised that you're using a custom repository. If you have access to the source code, I advise you to add a new method called `.FirstOrDefault()` that will take as parameter a predicate and returns null if no entities are found.

Edit 2: Add this method to your repository:

```
T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) 
{ 
    IQueryable<T> query = AsQueryable(); 
    query = PerformInclusions(includeProperties, query); 

    return query.FirstOrDefault(where); 
}
```

Then you can do something like this in your code:

```
foreach (var versionDetail in versions)
{
    bool isNew = false;
    var detail = versionDetail;

    var dbVersionentity = _productVersionEntityRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == detail.Id);

    // not found in database
    if(dbVersionentity == null)
    {
        isNew = true;

        // create entity here
        dbVersionentity = new .....; 

        // you don't need to do this if id is auto-generated, 
        // i.e. Identity column in SQL Server
        dbVersionentity.Id = GetNextTableId("vProductVersion");
    }

    dbVersionentity.Name = detail.Name;
    dbVersionentity.Code = detail.Name;


    if (isNew)
    {
        _productVersionEntityRepository.Insert(dbVersionentity);
    }
    else
    {
        _productVersionEntityRepository.Update(dbVersionentity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to find option of FirstOrDefault as asked in my original question. What am i missing?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now your problem. What type is `_productVersionEntityRepository`? Is it a custom repository? Is it a `DbContext` or `ObjectContext`?

Comment: i define it like 
private readonly Repository<ProductVersionEntity> _productVersionEntityRepository;

then i initialise it like below


 _productVersionEntityRepository = new Repository<ProductVersionEntity>(_objectSetFactory);

Comment: Also its custom repository and its objectContext. i can see First method defined here. How to add FirstOrDefault method?

Comment: The first method is defined as below in Repository.cs file 

  public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = AsQueryable();
            query = PerformInclusions(includeProperties, query);
            return query.First(where);
        }

Comment: You're wlecome @AshReva :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var dbVersionentity = _productVersionEntityRepository.Where(x => x.Id == detail.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It doesnt allow me to use Where as well

Comment: @AshReva you might need to add `using System.Linq;` to your class file.